# Sum containing primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Can anybody compute the value of $$\sum_p\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\log(p^k)}{k}-\sum_p\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\sum\limits_{p^n<k}\log(p^n)}{k(k+1)}$$ I have tried a lot but cannot think about the value of the sum.

Comment: `\sum` is a different command than `\Sigma`. Also, what are the limits on these sums?

Comment: It's an infinite sum starting from k=2. Sorry for bad formatting it was typed from a phone

Comment: You seem to be using $(p^k\lt n)$ as a number. What does that mean? Are you using [Iverson brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)?

Comment: What is $n$ in the numerator of the second summation?

Comment: Is it supposed to be $\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\log(p^k)}{k}-\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\sum_{p^n<k}\log(p^n)}{k(k+1)}$ and the sum in the numerator is summed from $n=2$? and $n$ is increased until $p^n$ reaches k?

Comment: That was intended to be subscript

Comment: In first sum the log is of prime or power of prime and in second sum it's log of all prime powers before k

Comment: I have edited your question. Please check whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which is the correct version of the question, so I won't specify all the indices.

It seems that both sums change indices the same way, so I suggest writing
$$\sum \left( \frac{\log(p^k)}{k} - \frac{\sum\limits_{p^n<k} \log p^n}{k(k+1)} \right)$$

Next you could use $\log a^b = b \log a$ to get:
$$\sum \left( \log p  - \log p  \frac{\sum\limits_{p^n<k} n}{k(k+1)} \right)$$

Now you either go on by yourself or specify if you want it summed over $p$ and what is the lower bound for $n$.